# How to position an element on an SVG path at certain point?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've been searching for hours for a tutorial on how to re-create the map/chart functionality displayed on this page.

When you hover your cursor over the histogram chart at different points (which shows elevation) it moves a pin/cursor on the google map to indicate what point on the map the elevation relates to.

Hard to explain but easier if you click on the link and see for yourself.

https://www.greaterhobarttrails.com.au/track/north-south-track/

[map & chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDH2n.jpg)

Any guidance is appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

John.

Comment: Maybe my [pathAnimator](https://github.com/yairEO/pathAnimator) tiny lib will be of assistance

Comment: Please write **titles** which describe the problem and are not generalized

Comment: Basically you can use my pathAnimator plugin to set your point on the map in the right location, because you know the `x` percentage of the bottom chart (use the pageX mouse event argument) and then you can position some pointer on the path of the map. easy.

Comment: There was a version of the [Google Elevation Path](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/elevation-paths) example that had that functionality (it looks like it doesn't do that anymore).  [Here is a copy of the example that I modified to add a distance computation to](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/elevation-paths)

Answer (score 0):

Below are just some guiding points, how to approach this task(probably not the best solution, but should work).

As the first requirement in your path array each point should have three properties - latitude, longitude, elevation.

To build the chart you need to use some of the chart libraries - it should support the mouseover event (here are some examples for chart libraries - https://www.sitepoint.com/15-best-javascript-charting-libraries/). Y-axis is elevation, X-axis can be distance from the beginning of the path(distance should be calculated for each point beforehand).

As the third step you need to show your path on the map - to do that you can use google maps api (https://developers.google.com/maps/).

In the end you need to connect chart and map, you need to subscribe for mouseover event from the chart. When handling that, you're interested in which path point is currently hovered by user. Afterwards you can take coordinates from it and add a marker on the map based on these coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

I can point you to the right direction with some helping methods from my own plugin [pathAnimator](https://github.com/yairEO/pathAnimator/blob/master/js/pathAnimator.js):

1. You need to attach a `mousemove` event on the bottom element (in your specific example) so you can get the `x` percentage (from `0` to `100`).
2. using the above value, use pathAnimatorm or any of it's methods, to position your marker element on the path of the map at the right point.
   you can use `pointAt` method for that, check the demo at the link above and you'll understand how it's done.